# Filtering a report in Access to show 2 different values

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I currently have a report in which it is filtered based on this criteria [Please enter QMWR, GRA, ER, or ERG:]. I would like to add a new option "Both" to select both ER and ERG. I have included the query below.

```sql
SELECT tblQMWR.QuarterID, tblQMWR.Page, tblQMWR.ProjectNum, tblQMWR.Employee, tblQMWR.DateSent, tblQMWR.DateReceived, tblImport.[Child PI S Name] AS PIName, tblQuarters2.Quarter, tblImport.[Child SPFMS Initials], tblPIContact.Office, tblQMWR.Notes, tblQuarters2.Type
FROM ((tblImport 
  RIGHT JOIN tblQMWR ON tblImport.[Child Flex Value] = tblQMWR.ProjectNum) 
  LEFT JOIN tblQuarters2 ON tblQMWR.QuarterID = tblQuarters2.QuarterID) 
  LEFT JOIN tblPIContact ON tblImport.[Child Department] = tblPIContact.Department
WHERE (((tblQMWR.Page) Is Not Null) 
  AND ((tblQuarters2.Quarter)=[Please enter a semester/ quarter code:]) 
  AND ((tblQuarters2.Type)=[Please enter QMWR, GRA, ER, or ERG:]) 
  AND ((tblQMWR.ProjectNum) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY tblImport.[Child PI S Name], tblQMWR.ProjectNum;
```

Thanks for the help! I ended up adding a second dialogue box so that any combination of 2 types can be used.

Comment: And what about QMWR and GRA?

Comment: Currently there is no records with QMWR or GRA. The only records have either ER or ERG.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( 1 line changed)

```
SELECT tblQMWR.QuarterID, tblQMWR.Page, tblQMWR.ProjectNum, tblQMWR.Employee, tblQMWR.DateSent, tblQMWR.DateReceived, tblImport.[Child PI S Name] AS PIName, tblQuarters2.Quarter, tblImport.[Child SPFMS Initials], tblPIContact.Office, tblQMWR.Notes, tblQuarters2.Type
FROM ((tblImport 
  RIGHT JOIN tblQMWR ON tblImport.[Child Flex Value] = tblQMWR.ProjectNum) 
  LEFT JOIN tblQuarters2 ON tblQMWR.QuarterID = tblQuarters2.QuarterID) 
  LEFT JOIN tblPIContact ON tblImport.[Child Department] = tblPIContact.Department
WHERE (((tblQMWR.Page) Is Not Null) 
  AND ((tblQuarters2.Quarter)=[Please enter a semester/ quarter code:]) 
  AND ([Please enter QMWR, GRA, ER, or ERG:] Like "*" & tblQuarters2.Type & "*" ) 
  AND ((tblQMWR.ProjectNum) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY tblImport.[Child PI S Name], tblQMWR.ProjectNum;
```